How to understand a strange command linked to Delaunay and Line2D?
I was intrigued by a command line that I don't understand, given in the answer of the (already old) post HERE.
So, I tried to investigate and made the following program:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D 
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay, delaunay_plot_2d

np.random.seed(12345)
points = np.random.rand(8, 2) 

tri = Delaunay(points)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
D = delaunay_plot_2d(tri, ax=ax)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

list = [l for l in D.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is Line2D]
list

which gave me 3 items in the list:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x246dd230550>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x246dd230850>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x246dd230af0>]

I then could use the 1st item to change the color of the points:
patch_point = [l for l in D.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is Line2D][0] 
patch_point.set_color('blue')

and the 2nd item to change the color of the lines:
patch_line = [l for l in D.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is Line2D][1] 
patch_line.set_color('green')    

but what is the meaning of the 3rd item? For example, the following lines doesn't change anything...
patch_what = [l for l in D.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is Line2D][2] 
patch_what.set_color('red')    

Could someone help me understanding what this strange command [l for l in D.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is Line2D] does?

That's not a strange command.  It just returns a list of the child objects of the first axis that are objects of class Line2D.  There are probably other child objects, like the tick marks and axis labels.

D.axes[0].get_children() are all the matplotlib elements that belong to the subplot. Some of them can be temporary objects, not visible in the plot (e.g. elements used to create a legend).  The exact order of the elements, the number of elements etc. are considered "internal kitchen" for matplotlib. This can change without notice in subsequent versions (of matplotlib and/or scipy).  Some changes to a plot can't be achieved without touching these elements (or extracting information from them), but there is no guarantee that such code will stay working in the future.

The "strange command" is an example of a "list comprehension", which is very common in python.

If you'd inspect the source code of delaunay_plot_2d, you'll notice that it just calls ax.plot() to draw the vertices, and then ax.triplot() to draw the triangulation.  Depending on the parameters, ax.triplot can also draw the vertices. This is the third line2D object (empty in this case). To get more control, you can just call the 3 code lines inside delaunay_plot_2d manually, with extra parameters.

See When to Use a List Comprehension in Python for an introduction to list comprehensions. (By the way, you shouldn't call your variable list as built-in Python function that won't be accessible anymore.)


but what is the meaning of the 3rd item?

2/3 of the Line2D objects (triangles edges + marker nodes) are made by triplot and the third one by plot. Actually, delaunay_plot_2d uses these two under the hood to make the visualization.
IMHO, using .plot() doesn't seem necessary here by scipy.
Here is a configuration to highlight the three different objects :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1, l2 = plt.triplot(
    points[:, 0], points[:, 1], tri.simplices,
    color="blue", marker="X", mfc="yellow", ms=10,
)

l3, = plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], "or", markersize=15, zorder=1)

plt.show()



Hi, @Timeless, very interesting! However, when I replace your fmt "or" by the supposedly equivalent marker="o", color="red", the plot is changed by... 2 new redlines! I can't find any explanation. do you understand where this comes from? Thanks.

You just need to understand how .plot() works. The docs says "Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers."

OK. Now adding marker="o", color="red", linestyle="None" restores the situation. Is that what you meant?
